# OpenCart - Private Email about Product

Tags: opencart

I'm new to OpenCart and not entirely sure if I can explain what I'm looking for in a way that makes sense.

Customer goes to a product page and is interested in a product but wants to talk to admin/seller about the specific product. I don't think a "questions" tab would be good because everyone can see that and that's not quite what I have in mind (thought might be depending on how it goes when we finally open our site). Something that would notify admin about a question submitted about a particular product.

I would search the OpenCart Extensions, but I'm not sure what this would be called.

Any and all help would be appreciated!

Comment: The easiest solution is to make **Contact Us** link more visible on the product details page. Then customer can write an email to you (your admin) directly. Or is it something else that you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

[Ask a Question V.3](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=7868) - some design modification, and your ready to go.